# Inserting data into a database using servlet returns a blank page

Tags: java, html, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get two inputs from an html and insert them in to my database. I have tried with bosth .jsp and .html files but no luck. When the jsp/html is called it returns a white page. Instead, I would like to prompt the html/jsp page to ask for the input. What am I doing wrong???

**my eclipse tree**

[image]

**AddInfo.java servlet**

```
 package controllers;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

@WebServlet(description = "A simple database connection", urlPatterns = { "/request" })
public class AddInfo extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2035938036539261609L;
    private String LOGIN_PAGE = "request.jsp";
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException{ 

            }   
    // Method to handle POST method request.
    @Override
     protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {


         response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
         PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();


         String con, QueryResult = null;
            DataSource dataSource = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            String rs = null;


      try {
            Context initContext = new InitialContext();
            Context envContext = (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            dataSource = (DataSource)envContext.lookup("jdbc/testdb");
            conn  = dataSource.getConnection();

            String name = request.getParameter("name");  
            String date = request.getParameter("date");  


              PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("insert into Campaign values(?,?,?)");

              pst.setInt(1,11);  
              pst.setString(2,name);        
              pst.setString(3,date);


              QueryResult = "Added Information!";

              int i = pst.executeUpdate(); 

              if(i!=0){  
                pw.println("<br>Record has been inserted"); 

                response.sendRedirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
              }  
              else{  
                pw.println("failed to insert the data");  
               }  

            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NamingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try { 
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <resource-ref>
  <description>Database</description>
  <res-ref-name>testdb</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>

  <servlet>
     <description></description>
     <display-name>AddInfo</display-name>
     <servlet-name>AddInfo</servlet-name>      
    <servlet-class>controllers.AddInfo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddInfo</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>page2.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>page2.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>page2.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

  </web-app>
```

**request.html**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" id="AddInfo" action="AddInfo">
<p>
Enter name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
Enter date: <input type="text" name="date"><br>
</p>
<br>
<p>
<input type="submit">
</p><br>
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: You see the blank page as soon as you run the application on your server or after you submit the input?

Comment: I see the white page once I redirect to the servlet page: http://localhost:8080/TomcatDataSourceApplication/request

Comment: I don't see where you redirect or forward in your servlet, also from your snap shot I can see there's an error in your eclipse project

Comment: Can you help me with that? That might be my problem but I am not sure how to implement it. I have looked around on other posts but no luck

Comment: Before you try to apply my answer below, what is the error in your IDE(hover over the red mark in your project)?

Comment: java compiler level does not match the version of the installed java project facet

Comment: Right-click on your project - Click Properties - Click the "Project Facets" option on the left menu - Under Facets section "Java" on the right, change it to your installed version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96072/discussion-between-user01230-and-perdomoff).

Comment: I added you suggestion below but it did not do anything. I am trying to open the request.html page, add the values and then insert them in to the db.

Comment: You have to clear that compiler error.

Comment: The compiler error is gone. Thank you for that. I was talking about the Forward response

Comment: no errors. still seeing the white page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I made changes to the web.xml, request.html and the servlet. I created the project and tested it. Try it. Post the follow up questions.

You need to forward or redirect your  response to a page(jps/html) like so:

```
       String nextJSP = "/index.html";
       request.getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP).forward(request, response);
```

Redirect:

```
  private String LOGIN_PAGE = "request.html";
  // other code here ...
  response.sendRedirect(LOGIN_PAGE);
```

Either would go at the end of your post method, depending on your reason for forwarding and page it goes too, for example you would ideally forward a successful scenario to the page you see fit.

EDIT --> Changes to the html page
request.html: Rename to index.html first.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="POST" id="identifier" action="AddInfo">
<input type="text" id="Id" name="Id">
<input type="submit" id="sub" name="button"/>
</form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Web.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

 <resource-ref>
  <description>Database</description>
  <res-ref-name>testdb</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
  </resource-ref>



 <servlet>
<description></description>
<display-name>CaseDeleteServlet</display-name>
<servlet-name>CaseDeleteServlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>servlets.CaseDeleteServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet>
     <description></description>
     <display-name>AddInfo</display-name>
     <servlet-name>AddInfo</servlet-name>      
    <servlet-class>controllers.AddInfo</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddInfo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AddInfo</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
   <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>

  </web-app>
```

Comment: @user01230,  Here is where you should be considering forwarding your response:

   if(i!=0){  
            pw.println("<br>Record has been inserted");  
/*HERE*/

          }  
          else{  
           /*HERE*/
            pw.println("failed to insert the data");  

           }

Comment: thats exactly where I added it... and it does not work. Thanks for the input

Comment: @user01230, Make sure the html page references the right servlet and servlet method in the form tags.  Also does your insert happen successfully?

Comment: It does not work. Why would we forward the response after the record has been inserted? This does not make sense to me.. I need to ask the user for the record values..

Comment: @user01230, you need to forward the response because you need to display a screen or message to the user with a notification or next steps.  Does your insert happen? Does the program enter this condition:

 if(i!=0){ pw.println("<br>Record has been inserted");

Comment: Put the snippet outside of the condition to see the forward happen, then we'll take a look at the insert:

 request.getRequestDispatcher("/request.html").forward(request, response);

if(i!=0){  
                   pw.println("<br>Record has been inserted");}

Comment: @user01230, Try this code now, make all changes and let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: I tried it but I still get the blank page.. I edited my initial code above with what I currently have/tested

Comment: @user01230 I took your exact code and created a project out of it and it works, what exact changes did you make, did you replace the web.xml and how are you compiling after you make the changes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96161/discussion-between-user01230-and-perdomoff).

Comment: actually it worked after I renamed the request.html to index.html... Thank you very much :)

Comment: One more question for you: I would like my index page to have two seperate links, and when I click the second link it will redirect me to this form (html). How can I achieve this with the web.xml?

Comment: @user01230,  you would create your jps/html page, add your hrefs for these pages in the index.html and forward or redirect just like above to these new pages.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for everything